# Android Marketplace - Installing apps remotely show as Installed even if phone is off?

Tags: android, security, google-play

Someone stole my phone last night in a matter of a few minutes. A friend mentioned the Android app "Plan B" which can be remotely installed from the Google website. My question is regarding the actual state of being installed.

After clicking 'Install', it reports the app as 'Installed', but I'm assuming this is not a true state of things as it took only a page load to report it as installed. The question is:

After clicking install on the Google Play website, if the phone is off or otherwise unavailable, will it still report the app as installed?

---

Also, going in to 'My Orders' from the cogwheel in the top-right corner, it shows the app install status as 'Complete'. Again, I don't know if these are real or assumed statuses.

The easy way to answer these questions is to turn off your phone, install any app from the Google Play website, and check to see if the app is marked as both "installed" and "complete" under the order area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this situation with my Nexus 4. I placed my Nexus 4 into the airplane mode (which has zero connectivity) and when to the playstore websited and install a random app. It said "Installed".

I then turned airplane mode off and then the new app instantly started installing as soon as my device connected to wifi.

Most android phones keep a very tight connection to the playstore. So as soon as the phone is turn on and connected to the Internet, it should auto-install right away. The only issue I can think of is that if your change your playstore settings to not autoupdate. Do you know if you enable that setting?

tldr;
Yes it lies to you. But As soon as the device is online and has internet connection it technically should install.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed as such, but this type of question is near impossible to find the answer by a search. Thanks for taking the time to answer this.

I believe I did turn off auto updates, I normally do that with everything, but I'd think installing is different than updating. At least I hope. I guess that would be another question: Does disabling autoupdates prevent autoinstall?

Comment: Oh, regarding the question whether it did show as 'Completed' in the 'My Orders' area, it seems that is a lie too (no actual validation). I just tried installing a larger app and it instantly was reported as 'Completed'.